# Rewrite-rules causes "Bad request" when placed in virtual host file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, bad-request

My clients webhost insists on placing the Rewrite-rules for the site in the virtual host file, but this causes the error "Bad request". Although when I place the same rules in a .htaccess on my local server, and other similar sites, it works perfectly. Here are the rules:

```
    RewriteRule ^api/ index_rest.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^index_rest.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?content/treemenu.* index_treemenu.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^var/([^/]+/)?storage/images(-versioned)?/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^var/([^/]+/)?cache/(texttoimage|public)/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^design/[^/]+/(stylesheets|images|javascript)/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^share/icons/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^extension/[^/]+/design/[^/]+/(stylesheets|flash|images|lib|javascripts?)/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^packages/styles/.+/(stylesheets|images|javascript)/[^/]+/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^packages/styles/.+/thumbnail/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^var/storage/packages/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^favicon.ico - [L]
    RewriteRule ^design/standard/images/favicon.ico - [L]
    RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]
    RewriteRule ^w3c/p3p.xml - [L]
    RewriteRule .* index.php
```

My host has given me an error log which is [located here](http://pastebin.com/sst6jkjv), but I cannot identify the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use leading slashes when using in the VirtualHost context.

> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against
>   the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query
>   string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").

So `^...` must be `^/...`

Comment: I see you could also put the rules inside a `<directory /your/path>`

Comment: yes, strictly speaking the equivalent of .htaccess is a Directory and it may be important for usage of some constants like REQUEST_URI but here rules seems simple and with a slash they should work, maybe with a slash as well on the rewrited url